# Django serializer field with more than one type

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

I need to create a field that is either a `CharField` or a list of char fields.

Pseudo code:

```py
class MySerializer(Serializer):
   my_field = CharField() | ListField(child=CharField())
   ...
```

I also need it to be properly recognised by DRF Spectacular so that the API docs state it can be either of those two field types.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read about SerializerMethodField, you could verify if your field is a list or char.

Comment: Read about create custom filed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-model-fields/